# Scraping Json Data from a REST Api

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scraper

I am learning Firebase with Android and I need a database to play with. This is the Json request url :https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json . 
It contains around 5000 movie List that I need. So I searched around internet and I found a tool called Scrapy. But I have no idea how to use it in a rest API. Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Please show us some code that you've tried so far. Here's the `scrapy` documentation for you to learn from. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html

Comment: Thanks i'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to follow the [Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to create a scrapy project, and then your spider can be as simple as this:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json']

    def parse(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.body)
        for movie in json_response['data']['movies']:
            yield Request(movie['url'], callback=self.parse_movie)

    def parse_movie(self, response):
        # work with every movie response
        yield {'url': response.url}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. Follow [the tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and start from the URL of your REST endpoint. On your `parse()` or `parse_item()` function, use `json.loads(response.body)` to load the JSON document. Since Scrapy now can ingest dicts, your code might be as simple as

```
import json
...

def parse(self, response):
    return json.loads(response.body)
```

[Here](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/638709df1fc6edeb4ad45f410095e1fe0253757a/ch05/properties/properties/spiders/api.py#L19)'s a slightly more advanced use case.